# Install Icecast into Linux

Tags: linux, icecast

I have no experience to linux system, and i would like to help me to solve this issue..
Now i have the following job..

```
cd ~
cd home
cd myusernmae
mkdir src
wget http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/icecast/icecast-2.3.2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf icecast-2.3.2.tar.gz
cd icecast-2.3.2
./configure
Error so i type the followings
apt-get install libxslt1-dev
sudo apt-get install libogg-dev libvorbis-dev
./configure
make
make install
cp -R /home/username/icecast-2.3.2/web ~/icecast/
```

Now when i type icecast shell response with the following message

```
Icecast 2.3.2

usage: icecast [-b -v] -c <file>
options:
        -c <file>       Specify configuration file
        -v              Display version info
        -b              Run icecast in the background
```

I know how can i use icecast into windows (icecast configuration file) but i don't know where to find it and how modify it into linux (vi editor :( )
Any help would me usefull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is an Ubuntu or a Debian based system, a simple `sudo apt-get install icecast2` should install the server for you without polluting your system. The configuration file is usually in `/etc/`. If it is Debian or Ubuntu, doing a `dpkg -L icecast2 | grep etc` after installing should show you the config files. Fire up an editor, edit them and then restart the service.

Comment: Try a `sudo make uninstall` where you compiled the source. I'm not sure that it will work since it just copied the files. Usually, these things install under `/usr/local` in which case, you could go there and delete the extra files. Why did you compile it in the first place though? You used `apt-get` to install `libvorbis` and others. You could have done the same with icecast itself.

Comment: i haven't install ubuntu in the server..
Someone else install it for me..
sudo make unistall doesn't work
should i try to install icecast2 without unistall what i have done?
I install it there because i read http://en.flossmanuals.net/icecast/linux-source/

Comment: I suppose you could. The thing you installed will just lie there.

Comment: http://en.flossmanuals.net/icecast/linux-debian-or-ubuntu/ is what you should have followed since you're using Ubuntu.

Comment: i try apt-get remove icecast
But shell responses "Couldn find package icecast"... same error with icecast-2.3.2

Comment: sudo make uninstall with the user i install the package works!!
Now, icecast==>Command not found..
Everything ready for new installation?